# Triggers and cursors

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new in triggers and I'm trying to create one. So, the trigger has to give an error when I introduce a date and the subtraction between this date and the old dates with same key are less than 1. So, my code is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pickup
BEFORE INSERT ON Pickingup
FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
 substraction INTEGER;
 BEGIN
SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(:new.date - date))) INTO substraction FROM Pickingup WHERE (:new.Id = Id AND :new.Year = Year);
IF (substraction < 1) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20600, :new.date || 'Error');
END IF;
END;
```

After this, I introdice a new value and I get this error:

```
exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Could someone give me any clue or help about what do I have to do?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired ersults.

Answer (score 0):

When you select INTO a variable, that variable can only contain a single value.  Therefore, your SELECT must return only one row.  Your

```
WHERE (:new.Id = Id AND :new.Year = Year)
```

is returning more than one row.  That is you have more than one row that satisfies the WHERE condition.

Comment: I tried using cursors, but I still get the same error:

Comment: But of course you did not show your code where you "tried using cursors".  Can you debug code that you cannot see?  Neither can anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger has several issues:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM(:new.date - date))) 
INTO substraction 
FROM Pickingup 
WHERE :new.Id = Id AND :new.Year = Year;
```

- The SELECT statement may return more than one row. An `SELECT ... INTO ...` must return exactly one row - no more, no less.
- `DATE` is a reserved keyword in Oracle, by default you cannot use it as column name. Choose a different name.
- I guess `date` column is a `DATE` data type. The difference of two `DATE` value is number (the difference in days). You can use `EXTRACT` only on `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` values, not numbers or [INTERVAL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i78291).

  Try `24 * (:new.date - date)` to get the difference in hours.
- Within a Row-Level trigger you cannot select the triggering table, i.e. you defined a trigger on table `Pickingup`, thus you cannot select table `Pickingup` within your trigger.

  You will get an `ORA-04091: table Pickingup is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error.
- Most people feel `WHERE Id = :new.Id AND Year = :new.Year` is better readable than your code (but that's just cosmetic).

Your actual requirement is not so clear to me, please provide sample data and expected results.